# Finding the default subnet mask, the network address, and the broadcast address of a Class D IPv4

Tags: networking, ip, ipv4

In the address 225.97.13.7 (Class D) how would I go about finding the default subnet mask, the network address, and the broadcast address, known that it's in IPv4?

Would it even be possible to do so? Class D seems odd with this type of stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This address is from the multicast range – it cannot be *used* for building subnets at all, and such things as a "subnet mask" do not apply to it as multicast is routed quite differently.

---

In general, the concept of "default subnet mask" is also long gone for all IPv4 addresses. Even the original defaults for classes A/B/C no longer correspond to reality in any way.